# Why doesn't this answer qualify for the Populist badge?

Tags: support, badges

My answer on " [Should I shoot underexposed photos?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/10898/should-i-shoot-underexposed-photos/10899#10899) " - has 20 votes, and the accepted answer has 10.  Why isn't this the Populist badge?
Populist - "Provided an answer that outscored an accepted answer with 10 votes by 2x"

Comment: photo-SE also judges the worthiness of the badge recipient. Sorry, but you weren't deemed worthy of the Populist badge. It's a really, really complicated algorithm...

Comment: @JayLancePhoto - If its that complicated, it probably has something to do with the exposure triangle ;)

Comment: Where ya been? Exposure Cube is the *new math*, man!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's > in both cases.

So the post must have 11 (> 10) and your answer must have > 22

[Is the Populist badge broken? Or have I misunderstood?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6851/is-the-populist-badge-broken-or-have-i-misunderstood/6886#6886)

I'll see if we can clarify the description there.

Comment: Thanks. Having 11 and 23 isn't clear AT ALL from the description.

Answer (score 0):

Yea, bug.  The query is probably looking for > 20, not >=.

Comment: ya, that was my thought as well